# Image not displaying when using application on a tablet

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch a camera activity and then capture the photo when the user saves it and return to the app. This works fine on my phone running Android 2.2 but I get a NullPointerException on my tablet running 4.1.2 or something.

I see the app is getting a NullPointerException in 'onActivityResult' when I try to make a bitmap out of the 'data' that's passed (clearly no data is getting passed):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera result time pauseTime should be reset: " + pauseTime);
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera resultCode is equal to: " + resultCode + " RESULT_OK is: " + RESULT_OK);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        try {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Data is null getting sent back
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error in logcat looks like this:

```
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at     com.android.thoughtfi.UsersThoughts.onActivityResult(UsersThoughts.java:163)
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5391)
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3215)
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3262)
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-29 17:16:50.795: W/System.err(19517):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
07-29 17:16:50.800: W/System.err(19517):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 17:16:50.800: W/System.err(19517):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 17:16:50.800: W/System.err(19517):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
07-29 17:16:50.800: W/System.err(19517):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Why isn't any data getting return to the application's onactivityresult?

EDIT (for extra info, here is the photoButton):

```
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // possible option
            String fileName = "temp.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

EDIT This seems to work ok, but I'm still getting the photo displayed in landscape mode no matter how I take it on the tablet:

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera result time pauseTime should be reset: " + pauseTime);
    Log.i(TAG, "Camera resultCode is equal to: " + resultCode + " ");

    Log.i(TAG, "The intent mCapturedImageURI was: " + mCapturedImageURI);

    Bitmap photo = null;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data != null){
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        } else {
                try {
                    photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mCapturedImageURI);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,
                null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
```

Photo BUtton:

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // possible option
            String fileName = "temp.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the line 163 of your UsersThoughts.java file?

Comment: It's where the exception is thrown: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Comment: Since you have the try catch block I don't see how the code you show is causing  the app to crash. Is your question why you get the NPE?

Comment: WEll I added the try catch block to prevent the code from crashing and see the error. The error is because of a NullPointerException, yes. That I don't understand. I guess I should make the question heading more specific

Comment: Android 4.0 and above has different handling for Image. Refer my answer to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682604/imageview-setimagebitmap-is-blank/17692578#17692578

Comment: @Brijesh Thakur, ahh that looks like it's working, but now it always displays a picture in landscape mode....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive) for the Camera, the doc state that it returns the path of the file containing the captured picture.

Relevant piece of code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to: " + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
          // whatever
        }
    }
```

EDIT: from [MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

> Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application
>   capture an image and return it.
>
> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image
>   will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small
>   sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is
>   useful for applications that only need a small image. If the
>   EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to
>   the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

If I understand this, the Camera activity returns either:

- the Uri of the full image, if EXTRA_OUTPUT was specified
- **or** a thumbnail in getExtras().get("data") if EXTRA_OUTPUT was not specified

Did you specify a EXTRA_OUTPUT param in the Intent launching the camera?

Comment: No i didn't specify it. Maybe in later versions the thumbnail is not automatically returned so one should use EXTRA_OUTPUT I will try it this way too and see how it works

Comment: actually I did have EXTRA_OUTPUT param in the intent. Thanks for the help this led to a good looking answer